# How to suffix or prefix each line coming from tail command

Tags: bash, shell-script, tail

I have a file and I am running a tail command on this file like this

```
tail -n+1 -F "./log/catalina.log"
```

I want to suffix or prefix another string to each line coming out of this file, which could be the file name itself so that if the file content is like below:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 27 2017 17:31:52 UTC
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.1.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
```

the output should look like this:

```
Cataline.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
Cataline.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 27 2017 17:31:52 UTC
Cataline.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.1.0
Cataline.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
```

Comment: Welcome, you say *"which **could be** the file name itself "*. *Could be* or *is* what you need? Depending on the case the answers may be different. Also the name of the file in the first command is `catalina.log`, but then in the output is `Cataline.log`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes, the filename itself is greatly helpful, now I say that at the beginning it wan't the main issue, but it now it became my issue. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect the filename in the other side of the pipe, you can use the `-v` option of `tail`, to always print the header, like this:

```
$ tail -v file
==> file <==
test1
test2
```

And you can catch the first line and make a prefix of it:

```
$ tail -vf file | awk 'NR==1{f=$2;next} {print f,$0}'
file test1
file test2
```

For the command above, the filename should have no whitespaces. A better version covering this case could be:

```
tail -vf file | awk 'NR==1{f=substr($0,5,length-8);next} {print f,$0}'
```

Or to use a custom prefix:

```
tail -vf file | awk 'BEGIN{p="custom prefix"} {print p,$0}'
```

Similar for a custom suffix:

```
tail -vf file | awk 'BEGIN{s="custom suffix"} {print $0,s}'
```

Comment: that was really helpful, but becasue of the requirements this won't work having the file name at the top of its content as it should be log lines being streamed into a log agent and the line that holds the file name will make it fail its purpose.
instead I would like to pass it to the awk command and to print it at the prefix instead of the constant word. If you can help me with this part, it would be really great, thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you please update your question with a reproducible case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
tail -f "./log/catalina.log" | awk '{print "Cataline.log",$0}'
```

or `sed`:

```
tail -f "./log/catalina.log" | sed 's/^/Cataline.log /'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `xargs`:

```bash
$ file="./log/catalina.log"
$ tail -n+1 -F "$file" | xargs -I {} echo "$(basename $file) {}"
catalina.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
catalina.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 27 2017 17:31:52 UTC
catalina.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.1.0
catalina.log INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
```