# How to prefix a value of variable before the each line coming from the tail command using the awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I am coming from this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704627/how-to-suffix-or-prefix-each-line-coming-from-tail-command) and I need to make the filename value to be stored in a variable and to use this variable in the `print` command instead of a static value

These were my trials but I am still unable to fix the line so that it works as expeted

```
filename=catalina.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log; tail -n+1 -F $filename | awk '{printf $filename"*"; print $0}'
```

Comment: Don't require us to go looking at other questions/links to find sample input/output and/or requirements. Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: Currently your question is identical to the linked one. How to prefix the logs with the filename. Also, you are presenting a command different than the existing answers there. You have not explained, by example, the reason why you ask the same question again.

Comment: It is 90% identical, but I was asking in the first time how to just prefix/suffix any string. Then I found that this string should be a variable and I couldn't edit the first question that's why I asked this question with the new addition. Thanks

Comment: @Ed Morton, thanks for the notice, I didn't know that rule in case it is a rule, but as the editor allows a hyper link this mean if a person wants to help he will go an d read the link. Anyway I am sorry  if it bothers you that much, you can just neglect the question.

Comment: @ShimaMahmoud You're welcome. I'm advising you how to get answers to your questions but it doesn't bother me in the slightest what you do. As you can tell by the lack of answers from all but 1 of the thousands of people who have read your question, I and most other people have indeed "neglected" it as you suggested. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-v` option of `awk`

```
filename=catalina.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
tail -n+1 -F "$filename" | awk -v file="$filename" '{printf "%s* %s\n",file,$0}'
```

where

- I use a single `printf` for both filename (in file variable), `*` and line
- I did not use `FILENAME` variable which is internal to `awk`.

Comment: It worked with me thanks alot :)